# Is there notation for the set of all odd positive integers?

Tags: notation

I want to denote the set of all odd positive integers. Is there a specific set notation for this?

Comment: One would be $\mathbb{N}-2\mathbb{N}$ but I feel like there's a better one.

Comment: I use $2\Bbb Z+1$ for all odd integers, but ymmv as there is no standardized notation, at least not for positives. You can do like $2\Bbb N -1$ also, I suppose, or $(2\Bbb Z+1)^+$ or something, but they'll all be gimmicky.

Comment: $1+2\mathbb N_0$ comes to mind.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Z}^+ \complement 2\mathbb{Z}$?